# Salvar vários dados com um único identificador em mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

Estou fazendo uma tela para mostrar os descontos no admin do opencart, por sub loja, já consigo salvar em uma tabela para testes, o maior problema é: Como deve ser feito corretamente nesse caso para ser salvo no BD?

- Preciso mostrar como tabela com a opção de deletar, em cada linha vai ter alguns dados como, Loja, porcentagem aplicada, data de início e fim e o delete.
- Os dados vem de várias tabelas.

Por exemplo: inclui um desconto em dez produtos para sub loja "A" e em mais 7 para a sub loja "B", originalmente, ambos os descontos são salvos em uma única tabela, mas pretendo criar outra tabela com referencia quais produtos é de qual sub loja, e mostrar na tela e poder deletar todas com uma botão.

Obs.: Faço assim, porque a tabela com os dados dos descontos não tem nada que referencie de qual desconto e de qual sub loja, fica tudo misturado, e eu não queria mexer nessa tabela, mas criar outra.

Tela demo:
[image: No quadrado vermelho é onde vão aparecer os descontos]
No quadrado vermelho é onde vão aparecer os descontos

Espero ter sido claro :)

Answer (score 1):

## Modelagem de loajas (já existente)

loja(id, nome, [...])

## Modelagem do produto (já existente)

produto(id, codigo, descricao, [...])

## Modelagem do desconto (Que eu faria)

desconto_loja(id, loja_id, produto_id, dataInicio, dataFim, per100)

primary kry (id)

foreign key (loja_id) para o id de loja

foreign key (produto_id) para o id de produto

unique index (produto_id, dataInicio)

Eu faria uma view que junte os dados de produtos, lojas e desconto e prepararia um layout que tenha como principal elo para deleção, o id de desconto.

Depois da view criada, você manda pro html o qye for mais conveniente só o id que ficaria obrigatório, pois com ele que deletaria os descontos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu pensei na seguinte coisa, criar uma tabela (oc3_product_special_discounts), por que vou ter que mostrar a porcentagem do desconto na tela de adição, esse dados não é armazenada em nenhuma tabela. entende?